# Homophones after vowel reduction

Tags: произношение

I tried to learn some Russian some 30 years ago and it's super rusty now but I'm trying to help my son who's taking it at school and is getting a bit discouraged by how daunting it is.

While revising some declensions, I've been wondering whether *книги* and *книге* are pronounced in the same way in everyday spoken Russian.  I have the same question about *доброе* and *добрая*.

Comment: _Kниги_ and _книге_ are pronounced differently, actually just the way they're written, _доброе_ and _добрая_ are pronounced the same way, as [ˈdobrəjə]. It is possible to differentiate them by pronouncing the last sound distinctly, as [e] and [a] (or [ɐ]) respectively, but don't pronounce the unstressed O as [o], it will sound weird, foreign or dialectal.

Comment: And there is [an online tool](https://easypronunciation.com/en/russian-phonetic-transcription-converter#phonetic_transcription) that produced IPA transcription of Russian word or even a text.

Comment: @YellowSky  Thank you for your answer.  The link you provide gives the same IPA transcription for книге and книги though, which is at odds with your first comment.

Comment: Well, personally I would agree that in "fast every day" speech *книге* and *книги* sounds indistinguishable. It does not however cause any ambiguity since the expected declension  (s vs. p and the case) is clearly obtained from surrounding words (The only ambiguous example I can come up with would be something like "Оставь его книге/книги" - but it's way too artificial).

Comment: @seven-phases-max True. Apart from the context one  would very rarely meet *книге* without a preposition. So this will typically be *в книге* (fknige), *о книге* (aknige), while *книги* is more often used in Nom. and Gen., i.e. without a preposition...

Answer (score 2):

It's all about vowel pronounced sometimes very short thus making sound "книги" and "книге" very similar. However when it pronounced slowly and/or clearly they are distinguishable to a native speaker. The same happens with `е` and `я` in "доброе"/"добрая".

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I take from your comment that when reciting, for example, a declension table "книге" and "книги" as well as "доброе" and "добрая" are sounded differently to clearly mark the difference in spelling, but that outside of artificial and self-conscious uses of speech, the two pairs are perfect homophones.

Answer (score 0):

While I agree that when книге/книги pronounced slowly and/or clearly they are distinguishable I would argue that доброе/добрая have differences in pronunciation

Comment: "I would argue" - based on what evidence? I can assure you that (if pronounced slowly and/or clearly) they also sound differently.

Comment: I don't need any evidence. This is my language and my opinion. How often do you pronounce words and sentences slowly? I doubt one could distinguish those words without context in everyday Russian

Comment: Well, we'll have to agree to disagree, then. This is my language too and my opinion is different from yours. What does the context have to do with this? I'm talking *specifically* about clear and slow pronunciation, *not* about everyday casual talks.